# JNI - Specify the own executable as source for native methods

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have started a Java VM with `JNI_CreateJavaVM`. I want my java classes to be able to use native methods exported from the executable that started `JNI_CreateJavaVM`.

All around google results, people tell you to use `System.loadLibrary` to specify what library to import native methods from. However, doing

```
public class someclass 
{
    static { System.loadLibrary("myExeName.exe"); }
}
```

will fail `FindClass` with

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no myExeName. in java.library.path
```

(I added `-Djava.library.path=.` as a `JavaVMOption`)

It seems Java cuts off the extension, which is a bummer as win32 `LoadLibrary("myExeName.exe");` works when having the extension. (But it might bite me when I try to port to another OS)

Anyway, my question is if there are other/better ways specify which module to import the natives from.

P.S I am aware there is `RegisterNatives`, but I'm hoping there to be a more automatic way.

Comment: I haven't tried, but if the symbols needed by your JNI calls are already loaded in your running binary, in theory you don't need the `LoadLibrary()` call.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I would be surprised if Java scans every modules export table in hope to find a function, but I'll try. Edit: In this case, `NewObject` fails with `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Package.Class.Method()V`. The .exe exports `Java_Package_Class_Method`.

Comment: RegisterNatives is nothing to be ashamed of, it's just one table, write it once, and it will do the job for you, no need to LoadLibrary. Well, you can always Syste.load("full/path/to/executable"), but why bother?

Comment: @AlexCohn Im not ashamed, just lazy :) Anyway, `System.load` fixed it. When I found it in the oracle documentation, I only read till "Loads a code file" and then went on while shaking my head ^^ You might want to post it as answer for some rep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give the full path of your executable (not hard to guess on any OS) into `System.load()` function, but RegisterNatives is not too much code to write.